# Stuck on a query and need support to improve the performance (if any) for the execution !(PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and I am learning by taking few examples!

I am solving a queries in PostgreSQL and I came with few but got stuck at one point!

Given the sample data in the SQLFiddle below, I tried:

```
--6.find most sold product with  with sales_id, product_name,quantity and sum(price)

select array_agg(s.sale_id),p.product_name,s.quantity,sum(s.price)
from products p
join sales s
on p.product_id=s.product_id;
```

but it fails with:

```
ERROR: column "p.product_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function:
```

This is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dbe7c/63) with sample data.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.

Comment: Is this homework / assignment work? I'd be interested in seeing where the examples came from.

Comment: these ar the sql queries given to be solved in our institute! its a last stocked document i'm trying these on PostgreSQL..Is there any problem with the queries ! @CraigRinger

Comment: some one suggested me not to keep homeworks or assigments until and unless u try them..so i tried upto my best and left out at that point! @craig Ringer

Comment: Sure, it's fine to ask for help when you were stuck, it's just nice to mention if it's an assignment or similar; people will be more inclined to try to guide you in the right direction and explain, not just say "here's how"

Comment: @CraigRinger thank u 4 the edit!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all that it looks simple, this is quite an interesting problem.

### The unsolved #6

There are two stages to this:

1. find the most sold product; and
2. display the required detail on that product

The question is badly written; it fails to specify whether you want
the product with the greatest number of sales, or the greatest
dollar sales value. I will assume the former, but it's easy to adapt the following queries to sort by total price instead.

**UPDATE**: @user2561626 found the simple solution I mentioned I was sure I was overlooking but couldn't think of: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dbe7c/118 . Use the output of `SUM` in `ORDER BY` then `LIMIT` the result set.

The following are the complicated and roundabout ways I tried because I couldn't think of the simple way:

One way is to use a subquery with an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to sort products by total number of sales, then pick the top one. You then join on that inner query to generate the desired product summary. In this case I join on sales twice, once in the inner query and once in the outer where I calculate more detail for just one product. It's possibly more efficient to join on it just once in the inner query and do more work, but that'll involve creating and discarding a bigger result set, so it's the sort of thing you'd tune based on your data distribution.

```
SELECT 
  array_agg(s.sale_id) AS sales_ids,
  (SELECT p.product_name FROM products p WHERE p.product_id = pp.product_id) AS product_name,
  sum(s.quantity) AS total_quantity,
  sum(s.price) AS total_price
FROM
(
  -- Find the product with the largest number of sales
  -- If multiple products have the same sales an arbitrary candidate
  -- is selected; extend the ORDER BY if you want to control which
  -- one gets picked.
  SELECT 
    s2.product_id, sum(s2.quantity) AS total_quantity
  FROM sales s2
  GROUP BY s2.product_id
  ORDER BY 2 DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS pp
INNER JOIN sales s ON (pp.product_id = s.product_id)
GROUP BY s.product_id, pp.product_id;
```

I'm honestly not too sure how to phrase this in purely standard SQL (i.e. no `LIMIT` clause). You can use a CTE or multiple scans in subqueries to find the greatest number of sales and the product Id with the greatest number of sales, but that'll give you multiple results if you have more than one product with equal sales.

I can't help but feel I've totally forgotten the simple and obvious way to do this.

### Comments on others:

```
--1.write the query find the products which are not soled
select * 
from products 
where product_id not in (select distinct PRODUCT_ID from sales );
```

Your solution is subtly incorrect, because there's no `NOT NULL` constraint on `product_id` in `sales`. It builds a list then filters on the list, but the list could contain `NULL`, and `2 NOT IN (1, NULL)` is `NULL`, which in `WHERE` is treated as false.

It is much better to re-phrase this as `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sales s WHERE s.product_id = products.product_id)`.

With #2 it's again better to use `EXISTS`, but PostgreSQL can optimize it into the better form automatically since it's semantically the same; the `NULL` issue doesn't apply for `IN`, only `NOT IN`. So your query is fine.

Question #7 highlights that this is an awful schema. You should *never* store split-up year/month/day like this; a sale would just have a single `timestamptz` field, and to get the year you'd use `date_trunc` or `extract`. That's not your fault, it's bad table design in the question. The question could also be clearer; I think you've answered it correctly as written, but they don't say whether or not years with no sales should be shown - presumably they assume there aren't any. If there are, you'd have to do a left outer join over a `generate_series` of dates to zero-fill empty years.

Question #8 is another bad question, frankly. "max price". Um. What? "Maximum price paid per item" would be "price/quantity". "Greatest total individual sale value for each product" would be what you wrote. The question seems to allow for either.

Comment: Thank u for this support!! i wil try further :-)

Answer (score 2):

The Query Solution for **Question#6** is ::

```
 select array_agg(s.sale_id),p.product_name,sum(s.quantity) as Quantity ,sum(s.price) as Total_Price
    from sales s,products p
    where s.product_id =p.product_id 
    group by p.product_id  
    order by sum(s.quantity) desc limit 1  ;
```

**Comment On Others**

Question#9: @Robin Hood's

```
select s.sale_id,p.product_name,s.quantity,s.price 
from products p,sales s
 where p.product_id=s.product_id and p.product_name LIKE 'S%';
```

the 'S%' is a case Sensitive .. so it how it works..

Question#10: @Robin Hood's

Stored Procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_details()
  RETURNS TABLE(sale_id integer,product_name varchar,quantity integer,price int) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    select s.sale_id,p.product_name,s.quantity,s.price 
    from products p 
    join  sales s
    on p.product_id =s.product_id ;

    Exception WHEN no_data_found then
RAISE NOTICE 'No data available';
    END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

**select * from get_details();** then you will get the result.

Comment: Is this a right way to code the Question#5 @craig Ringer

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense. You're picking the product with the highest ID number, not the most sold product. It might happen to work with the example data, but it is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: yup! u r right i'm such a fool did not evaluate Thank u @ craig Ringer

Comment: The Edited query  solved the purpose.. will it go wrong at any where @craig Ringer

Comment: Nicely done! I knew there was a simple standard way to do this - I completely forgot you could refer to aggregate results in `ORDER BY`. +1 that looks fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dbe7c/118

Answer (score 1):

I need a help over these questions even !! i just want to add these queries to.

--**Question#9**

```
--9. select product details with sales_id, product_name,quantity and price those product names are started with letter ‘s’

--This selects my product details   

 select s.sale_id,p.product_name,s.quantity,s.price
    from products p,sales s
    where p.product_id=s.product_id ;

--This is'nt working to find those names which start with s.. is there any other way to solve this..
 select s.sale_id,p.product_name,s.quantity,s.price
    from products p,sales s
    where p.product_id=s.product_id and product_name = 's%';
```

--10. write the stored procedure for extract all the sales and product details with sales_id, product_name,quantity and price with exception handling and raisint the notices

Comment: the Question#10 u need to alteast try to get the query solved and u dont get ur homework done here ! its just to make corrections and to support u ! Please come up with a query u solved and get your doubts clarrified, and the Question#9 is a good one wil be getting upto it @robin hood's

Comment: @user2561626 Thank you for the suggestions i wil come up with ur suggestions!

Comment: `
select s.sale_id,p.product_name,s.quantity,s.price
    from products p,sales s
    where p.product_id=s.product_id and p.product_name LIKE 'S%';

`

Comment: It is a case senstive so u had no errors or warnings displayed!!@robin hood's

Comment: This is mighty confusing - it looks like it's an answer containing more questions, but it's posted by "Robin Hood's" not "user2561626". Wha?! Are you and @RobinHood's in the same class or something?

Comment: @robin Hood's  From Where did you get the queries is that u found this some where --craig Ringer had a doubt that we r from a same class/ institute!! where r u from ---

Comment: @user2561626 no i just added those queries of my understanding and doubts left in my backpag! i'm not from any institute!!